# multithreading with javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, ionic-framework, geolocation, buffer

I need to use thread with javascript.I am using [this](http://keithwhor.github.io/multithread.js/) library.
I need to seperate my work to threads.
My thread function takes 2 arguments.`K1.union(K2)`.The thread combining two polygons.But jsts library doesn't work inside the `functDif` function.I can't solve this problem.Can you please help me to solve this ?

```
var geoReader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader(),
    geoWriter = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter();

var num_threads = 2;
var MT = new Multithread(num_threads);
var functDif = MT.process(function(K1, K2) {
    D = K1.union(K2);
    return D;
  },
  function(r) {
    console.log(r);
  }
);

A = geoReader.read(free.geometry).buffer(distance);
B = geoReader.read(free.geometry2).buffer(distance);
T = functDif(A, B);
```

Comment: usually you can't return anything from a callback, you have to push it out through a global or closure.

Comment: it doesn't work despite I defined it globaly.I don't know why jsts is not working only inside the `functDif`  function.

Comment: @seyidyagmur You defined a global variable and mutated it's state in the callback?

Comment: not in callback, I defined it both out of constructor and inside it.